# How to cut up a string from an input file with Regex or String Split, C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Edit: Since you guys were being a pain in my ass and not really saying much I just hacked together this attempt since someone wanted it. It does exactly what I want and yes it turns out that Regex is exactly what I needed to do what I wanted.

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
string temp; 

        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\final.header");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            /*if (counter == 5 && Regex.IsMatch(line, @"Read\=.*"))
            {
                counter = counter - 2;
            }*/

            switch (counter)
            {
                case 0:
                    temp = Regex.Replace(line, "##File List", string.Empty);
                    //Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    temp = line.Replace("Cc=", "");
                    //Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"Read\=.*"))
                    {
                      Console.WriteLine(line);
                      counter +=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"AttachmentName\=.*", string.Empty);
                    }  
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"parentId\=.*", "");
                    //Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"Bcc\=.*", "");
                    //Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"Date\=.*", "");
                    //Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"format\=.*", "");
                    //Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"To\=.*"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"AttachmentId\=.*", "");
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    break;
            }

            if (counter >= 12)
            {
                counter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to delimit/split this in C# and don't even know where to begin. All of the examples I've found about using string.split and regex.split are confusing me given that the following text is read in from a StreamReader.

```
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
```

test.txt:

```
##File List
#Tue Dec 13 14:27:43 CST 2011
Subject=Research paper.
From=zmeinecke
Cc=
AttachmentName=ADHD Medication Research Paper.docx
Read=true
parentId=
Bcc=
Date=1323748746221
format=blackboard.base.FormattedText$Type\:HTML
AttachmentId=b2cb1016f0b847a3bfae636988aa3f6a
To=ksanger;
```

Basically, I'm trying to get this to be the output:

```
Tue Dec 13 14:27:43 CST 2011    
Subject=Research paper.    
From=zmeinecke    
Read=true   
To=ksanger;
```

Thanks

Comment: probably start by splitting on newlines

Comment: Post your attempt please.

Comment: Looking at your code, `myString` is a string that contains the contents of the file. What have you tried to do with it? What are you finding confusing?

Comment: I can't find any examples of code that say "to cut text up to a certain pattern, use this regular expression" basically.

Comment: The comment in your edit is uncalled for. There were two responses (mine and that by @Jonesy) that provided simple and effective answers to to the question you asked. That you were unwilling to spend the time to understand those answers is not *our* fault. If those answers didn't solve your problem, it's because you didn't ask the right question. Remember, we don't have psychic powers to know what you're really trying to do, so you have to give us a clear complete description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

This regex will:

- capture the fields values for subject, from, to, and read
- the fields can be listed in the source string in any order
- capture the date on the second line what starts with a single `#`

`^\#(?!\#)([^\r\n]*)(?=.*?^Subject=([^\r\n]*))(?=.*?^From=([^\r\n]*))(?=.*?^To=([^\r\n]*))(?=.*?^Read=([^\r\n]*))`

[image]

## Expanded

- `^\#(?!\#)` match the first line which only has a single `#`
- `([^\r\n]*)` capture all characters on the line which are not new line characters
- `(?=` start the lookahead for the subject, this format is the same for each of field being looked for. by using a lookahead the fields can appear in any order

  - `.*?^Subject=` travel through the string until the first occurance of `subject` at the start of the line
  - `([^\r\n]*)` capture all non new line characters
  - `)` close the lookahead
- `(?=.*?^From=([^\r\n]*))` repeat the process for `from`
- `(?=.*?^To=([^\r\n]*))` repeat for `to`
- `(?=.*?^Read=([^\r\n]*))` repeat for `read`

The order in which the lookaheads occur in the regular expression dictacts the order in the values are captured. You can add more fields or rearrange them as desired.

## Example

Live example:  http://www.rubular.com/r/8y1xQZYj05

**Sample Text**

```
##File List
#Tue Dec 13 14:27:43 CST 2011
Subject=Research paper.
From=zmeinecke
Cc=
AttachmentName=ADHD Medication Research Paper.docx
Read=true
parentId=
Bcc=
Date=1323748746221
format=blackboard.base.FormattedText$Type\:HTML
AttachmentId=b2cb1016f0b847a3bfae636988aa3f6a
To=ksanger;
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"^\#(?!\#)([^\r\n]*)(?=.*?^Subject=([^\r\n]*))(?=.*?^From=([^\r\n]*))(?=.*?^To=([^\r\n]*))(?=.*?^Read=([^\r\n]*))",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
          Match m = re.Match(sourcestring);
          for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Capture Groups**

1. gets the date
2. gets subject
3. gets from
4. gets to
5. gets read

```
[1] => Tue Dec 13 14:27:43 CST 2011
[2] => Research paper.
[3] => zmeinecke
[4] => ksanger;
[5] => true
```

Comment: Awesome @Denomales, thank you very much for actual explanations of the different Regexes. In my code though actually it I use an input file that has the exact text as what's above, this is what gets outputted:
`[0] = #Tue Dec 13 14:27:43 CST 2011
[1] = Tue Dec 13 14:27:43 CST 2011
[2] = Research paper.
[3] = zmeinecke
[4] = ksanger;
[5] = true`

Any idea why?

Comment: The `[0]` portion is capture group zero which shows the entire matched string (not including the lookaheads). This group is always present in the returned capture groups.

Comment: Can I just set gIdx to 1 to skip over writing that line then? I mean it seems like a work around, is doing that the "correct" programmatic thing to do?

Comment: "correct" is always a matter of opinion. If that works then try it. I could probably rewrite the expression to omit the date field from group 1

Answer (score 3):

here's a start:

```
string date;
string subject;
string from;
string read;
string to;

foreach (string line in myString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    if(line.Contains("Subject="))
         subject = line;
    else if (line.Contains("From="))
         from = line;

    //......
}
```

Comment: ... Or just read it in line by line in the first place... But that's by far the best way to do this. +1

Comment: Does it matter if I'm sending my string to a rich text box? I'm doing txtBoxEmailRead.Text = myString;. But it doesn't seem to take any kind of string or regex splitting into account.

Comment: Ok, since you're going to be using your full file's text for the richtextbox, then you were right to save it into `myString` first. Then @Jonesy's solution is showing you that you don't need to use Regex splitting to accomplish this. You could use something like `line.Split("=")(1)` to get whatever comes after the equal sign, for example.... Just thougts...

Comment: Yeah, nothing is really helping. Some better examples that just explain how to cut certain strings in a given string would probably help me out a lot more but most examples talk about splitting lines and just escaping them to new lines..

Comment: His start doesn't even do anything to the output I'm getting in my program, so... I can't exactly take it and go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you read the entire file into a string? Things are much easier if you just read the file line-by-line:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\test.txt"))
{
    string trimmed = line.Trim();
    int pos = trimmed.IndexOf('=');
    if (pos == -1) continue;
    string category = trimmed.Substring(0, pos);
    string content = trimmed.Substring(pos+1);
    switch (category)
    {
        case "Subject":
            // do stuff
            break;
        case "From":
            // do stuff
            break;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

You could use `String.Split` or regular expressions to do the split. For simple things like this, I use `IndexOf` and `Substring` just because I find them easier.

Comment: Reading line by line doesn't work and only outputs the last line into a rich text box in visual c#.

Comment: @user1275954: The problem is the way you're adding text to your rich text box. If you call [AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) rather than setting the `Text` property, things should work just fine. Or, build the string into a `StringBuilder` and when you're done, set the `Text` property of the rich text box.

Comment: Why does this code trim the line that begins with #? I need to keep that line. I mean I appreciate getting a start but again don't really understand what it does. Most examples from MSDN/etc of trimming and splitting only talk mostly about single/special characters.

Comment: @user1275954: As the [documentation] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) states: `Trim()` "Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object." That's so you can deal with lines like "   Subject=foo    ". It turns the line into "Subject=foo".